# How to read multiple rows and columns in excel file with apache poi?

Tags: apache-poi

[I want read attached excel file (with Apache POI), after matching Question type = slider,  want to pass a value for respective class (created different classes according to question type)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PRbo5.png)

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**Why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: for excel file, click on (I want....)

Comment: Looking for creation array object and read object logic. Thanks in advance

Comment: "Looking for creation array object and read object logic." Yes, but that is not how StackOverflow works. [Read the docu of the API you are using](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html): concrete  [Getting the cell contents](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Getting+the+cell+contents) for example. Then try something your own and ask concrete questions if you are stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Use Fillo Java Jar.Its very simple where can access the data using queries.
Link for the tutorial :https://codoid.com/fillo/

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.codoid.products</groupId>
  <artifactId>fillo</artifactId>
  <version>1.18</version>
</dependency>
```